# Foundation baseline different in snapshot view than when created

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I created a snapshot view, all view access properties show the date i created it, date last modified, last accessd etc.. are all the date it should be April 10 BUT the Configurations tab shows a foundation baseline of the next release up May 10

Now I do it difrent; I create a child stream created with the older baseline and then make a snapshot but I would like to know why this snapshot I made 4/10 has a foundation baseline of 5/10 
Weird how it shows a foundation baseline that is newer than the date it was created, Maybe CC just knows this is the foudantion of this next release i guess

I did a compare and the files are still the same as the date I created the snapsot is appears but if not I am in trouble...

I am new to CC and devolpement
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents anybody to *rebase* the Stream you view is based on, from *antoehr* view.

Then, when you update your snapshot view, ClearCase will detect the change of configuration of the Stream and proposes to synchronize the config spec of your view with the Stream.
Hence the change of configuration of your view.

Whet you did in that case is correct: create a child Stream based on the right baseline, and work from there.

See "[Rebase operation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/images/rebase_details.gif)":

[image: rebase]

> A component in Pat’s development stream is configured with baseline `BL1`.
>   **A rebase operation changes the configuration of the stream to baseline `BL2` from the integration stream**.
>   The rebase operation merges files and directories from the integration stream or feature-specific development stream to the development stream.